# React.js - default prop is not used with `null` is passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have default props in my React component:

```
PropertyTitleLabel.defaultProps = {
    bedrooms: 1,
    propertyType: 'flat'
};
PropertyTitleLabel.propTypes = {
    bedrooms: PropTypes.number,
    propertyType: PropTypes.string
};
```

But when I'm passing `null` to `bedrooms` like:

```
const bedrooms = null; // in real world API returns `null`
<Component bedrooms={bedrooms} />
```

It's not replaced with default prop :( Any ideas?

Comment: Also, if you use a falsy value without `PropTypes.exact`, the default prop is not used either.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can change the `null` value to `undefined` to use the default value.

```
<Component bedrooms={bedrooms || undefined} />
```

Comment: As a helper for anyone else that might be landing here, please don't use mixins. @jagsler I hope you might consider updating your original answer. https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html

Comment: still not an elegant solution, so you are setting default props 2 times...

Answer (score 20):

I think there's a distinction between `null` and `undefined` that is made when dealing with the `defaultProps`. The `null` value could be intended behavior and thus isn't replaced by your defaults, while `undefined` is not and will be replaced.

As stated in the docs

> [...] used to ensure that this.props.value will have a value if it was not specified by the parent component.

Here is a [related issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2166).

Answer (score 3):

- `undefined` = nothing.
- `null` = something that hints "nothing".

`undefined` doesn't exist in reality. `null` however does exist. This means  `undefined` won't pass a prop value as you cannot pass something which doesn't exist. Since `null` is not nothing, but rather is something which only hints at nothing, it passes in props.

Answer (score 1):

From [React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f905da22762369975be71da5c13ff96796773039/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L254)

It seems React checks only if the value of the props is `undefined`.

```
    if (type && type.defaultProps) {
      var defaultProps = type.defaultProps;

      for (propName in defaultProps) {
        if (props[propName] === undefined) {
          props[propName] = defaultProps[propName];
        }
      }
    }
```