# Why do default props not protect against a TypeError when there is a destructuring assignment in a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that accepts a prop `a` that is an object with a property `b`:

```
const MyComponent = ({ a: { b } }) => b;

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  a: {
    b: 4,
  },
};
```

This component is connected to a Redux store:

```
export default connect(state => ({ a: state.a }))(MyComponent)
```

And the store seems to be very well protected against a type error:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { a: { b: 0 } };

const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // none of the branches of the switch statement removes state.a.b or reassigns state.a to something other than an object
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Sometimes, very rarely, in less than 1 out of 1000 requests, I see a corresponding

> TypeError: cannot read property 'b' of undefined

recorded in the exception monitoring system. There seems to be no correlation with the user's browser version. The latest stable build of React is running on production at all times. The other surrounding code is very unlikely to cause such behavior.

My question is, am I missing something about the way default props or Redux work? Do I have to write more defensive code around the destructuring assignment expression even when I have default props in place?

Comment: Why is a component just returning a number instead of JSX?

Comment: @John Ruddell this is irrelevant. The execution does not reach that point, it fails at the destructuring assignment that happens immediately before the function returns.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just asking about the component because this isn't correct. I wouldn't rely on default props, rather just make sure you're rendering the component with the correct props. If you want to create a codesandbox replicating the issue, the code you have provided looks fine. Hard to tell without seeing the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `defaultProps` correctly, but I suspect that `a` is somehow being set to `null` instead of `undefined`. `defaultProps` only replaces the props when the value is `undefined`, so if there is some case where `a` is set to null, the default props won't appear, which would cause your error.

From your example, it's not possible to tell where it's being set to null, but that's a place you can use to start your search. I would start looking in your redux reducer where the assignment is performed since it might be an endpoint unexpectedly returning `null`, or something along those lines.

Reference: [React.js - default prop is not used with `null` is passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809178/react-js-default-prop-is-not-used-with-null-is-passed)